# gionee e7 mini screen lock problem

Tags: screen, hardware

I aam using Gionee E7 mini. My phonee is working perfeectly but as soon i pick up up any call, the screen loacks and it reopens only when the other side hangs up.I am not able to disconnect any call in between vecause my screen go black. In call answering there is no problem but I cannot disconnect calls.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the proximity sensor. It should go black when it is close to your ear and turn on when you move it away. You could try [a proximity sensor calibration tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.zte.ProximeitySensorClib&hl=en_GB) and see if it helps. It might be a hardware issue, but try to narrow it down.